# use python variable to read specific rows from access table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an access table called "Cell_list" with a key column called "Cell_#". I want to read the table into a dataframe, but only the rows that match indices which are specified in a python list "cell_numbers".
I tried several variations on:

```
   import pyodbc
   import pandas as pd
   cell_numbers = [1,3,7]
   cnn_str = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\folder\myfile.accdb;'
   conn = pyodbc.connect(cnn_str)
   query = ('SELECT * FROM Cell_list WHERE Cell_# in '+tuple(cell_numbers))
   df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

But no matter what I try I get a syntax error.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert (join) `cell_numbers` to text:

```
cell_text = '(1,3,7)'
```

and concatenate this.

The finished SQL should read (you may need brackets around the weird field name `Cell_#`):

```
SELECT * FROM Cell_list WHERE [Cell_#] IN (1,3,7)
```

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Consider best practice of parameterization which is supported in [**`pandas.read_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html):

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT, NO DATA
query = (
    'SELECT * FROM Cell_list '
    'WHERE [Cell_#] IN (?, ?, ?)'
)

# RUN SQL WITH BINDED PARAMS
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=cell_numbers)
```

Consider even dynamic qmark placeholders dependent on length of `cell_numbers`:

```py
qmarks = [', '.join('?' for _ in cell_numbers)]
query = (
    'SELECT * FROM Cell_list '
    f'WHERE [Cell_#] IN ({qmarks})'
)
```